# Error Parse SDK: Cannot sign up user with an empty name

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform

I am trying to sign up users with the Parse SDK. My keys are correct and I have used my own code as well as the "Signing Up" code straight from [Parse Quickstart Tutorial](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-signup) and I keep getting this error message:

> Cannot sign up user with an empty name.

I have even hardcoded values into the signUp function, and printed the values (and typeof) out to the console for accuracy, but still not luck. Here's a snippet of the function I created, it's practically straight out of the tutorial.

```
var newUserEmail    = document.getElementById("new-user-email").value;
var newUserPassword = document.getElementById("new-user-password").value;
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("email", newUserEmail);
user.set("password", newUserPassword);
user.set("name", "no name");
user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user) {
        console.log("New user signed up successfully!");
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
        console.log("You messed up. Error: " + error.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set the `username`:

```
user.set("username", "my name");
```

From [Parse Quickstart Tutorial](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-signup) that you mentioned:

> If a signup isn't successful, you should read the error object that is returned. The most likely case is that the username or email has already been taken by another user. You should clearly communicate this to your users, and ask them try a different username.
>
> You are free to use an email address as the username. Simply ask your users to enter their email, but fill it in the username property — Parse.User will work as normal. We'll go over how this is handled in the reset password section.

Comment: Thanks, I was in similar situation and your solution worked. but i am also have same issue with         $user = ParseUser::logIn($email, $password);  i got Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'Cannot log in user with an empty name'